# Sketching a graph of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus

Given a function $f(x)$ is increasing in the intervals $(-\infty, -1 )$ and $(3, \infty)$, and decreasing in the interval $(-1,3)$

If I want to sketch a graph of $f(x)$,

I know that the maximum point $\implies x=-1$

Minimum Point $\implies x=3$

However, let's say given the graph

$-5<x<5$

$-5<y<5$

Is there anyway to make the graph nearly accurate from only the given information?

For example, at which $y$ coordinate point would the maximum and minimum point be at?  Or do I just take a random guess from the given information since I only want to sketch it?

Here is my sketch -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I'll assume your function is of the form $f:\mathbf{R}\to \mathbf{R}$. When you're asked to sketch a function or curve like this, you should just seek to include the information specified. In this case, just draw the graph so that it is increasing on $(-\infty,-1)$ and $(3,\infty)$, while decreasing on $(-1,3)$. Also, draw it so that the maximum point occurs at $x=-1$, and the minimum point occurs at $x=3$.

If you feel uncomfortable not knowing the $y-$values of your graph at $x=-1,3$, try simply labeling the $y-$value as $y=f(-1)$ and $y=f(3)$, respectively.

**EDIT:** I just saw your sketch now. That looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have no information about the $y$ values, so your sketch is fine. There are lots of functions that meet your description.